shared library not found but exists in nix flake
I'm currently learning nix flakes and made the following flake.nix to nix develop into an environment I'm declaring for developing alacritty
{
  inputs = { nixpkgs.url = "github:nixos/nixpkgs?ref=nixos-unstable"; };

  outputs = { self, nixpkgs }:
    let
      system = "x86_64-linux";
      pkgs = nixpkgs.legacyPackages.${system};
    in {
      devShells.${system}.default = pkgs.mkShell {
        nativeBuildInputs = with pkgs; [
          cargo
          cmake
          pkg-config
          fontconfig
          wayland
          libGL
          libxkbcommon
        ];
        # my ugly workaround
        # LD_LIBRARY_PATH =
        #   "/nix/store/blw10rx1cayp2n2pkmyihpipifzgj2xq-wayland-1.22.0/lib/:/nix/store/lgd89akyy4q51hf7cml73avxixy4qgan-libxkbcommon-1.5.0/lib/:/nix/store/1bapla8zwlx128i42wi08zbiibwk6gm3-libglvnd-1.7.0/lib";
      };
    };
}


So far I've managed to cargo build in the nix develop shell, but when cargo run-ning a bunch of "libxyz.so not found" errors popped up which I managed to solve by the workaround in my code snippet. Is there a proper mechanism in flakes that would allow me to resolve shared library dependencies properly?

You can make your workaround less ugly by using: LD_LIBRARY_PATH = pkgs.lib.makeLibraryPath nativeBuildInputs; Note that you will need a rec after pkgs.mkShell to access the nativeBuildInputs.
